# How to change textarea background color based on a specific choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a form with Name, Surname, a dropdown menu where the users can choose from different color and a message box (textarea). My idea would be to change the color of textarea background in according to the color chosen using the dropdown menu.

Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in adv,
Enrico

Comment: Have you tried at least *something* ?

Comment: Here's a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/HVNzh/

Comment: Other example http://jsfiddle.net/8JYuY/ and now go to study

Answer (score 0):

Make necessary improvements you need. This will get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/eTJGV/1/

Use jquery change property,

```
$('#color').change(function(){
    var color = $(this).val();
    $('textarea').css('background-color',color);
});
```